# Android use and modify a different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, sharedpreferences

I need to make and activity with a listview which shows all the apps installed, its name, icon and a switch so that when you click the item the switch state change and it has to be stored with sharedpreferences. I have used [this example](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android) and then add a switch on `snippet_list_row.xml`. For changing and storing the status of the switch, i´ve changed`AllAppsActivity.java` to:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
    Switch appSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.app_switch);
    if (appSwitch.isChecked()){
        appSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        appSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AppsNotificationsActivity.this).edit().putString(app.packageName , String.valueOf(appSwitch.isChecked())).commit();
}
```

But it doesn´t store or change the switch status, an I think it could be because it is not inside the activity layout. So, how could I fix it??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

In the onCreate method of your AllAppsActivity.java, add this lines of code:

```
setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, arrayOfApps ,arrayOfAppIcons));
```

where **arrayOfApps** is an array of String (app names) and **arrayOfAppIcons** is array of corresponding app icons.

Then create the code for CustomArrayAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String [] appnames;
private final IconType [] appicons; //Replace IconType by your icon images' datatype


public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] appnames,IconType[] appicons ) {
    super(context, R.layout.app_list_item_layout, appnames);
    this.context = context;
    this.appnames = appnames;
    this.appicons = appicons;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_list_item_layout, parent, false);

//The following variables are references to the elements within each list item displayed (in app_list_item_layout xml file)
    TextView appNameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
    ImageView appIconView = (ImageView)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);      
//If you are using something else to dislay app icons, replace ImageView by corresponding datatype
    Switch appSwitch = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.app_switch);


    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Do whatever u want here on any List item click
            // the variable "position" indicates which particular list item was clicked
        }
    });



    return rowView;
}
```

}

Note, **app_list_item_layout.xml** is a layout xml file where you define the layout style for *each item in your list*.

In the onCreate() method of your AllAppsActivity.java, you should set the layout to your main layout xml file.

You don't need to use your onListItemClick method after using this.

**EDIT:** In your main layout xml file, you should have a ListView element. Let its id be **appList**. So then put this code snippet in the *onCreate()* method of your AllAppsActivity.java:

```
appListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.appList); //appList element exists in your main layout xml file for your activity
appListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
appListView.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, arrayOfApps ,arrayOfAppIcons));
```

The earlier code I mentioned is a more generalized version, but you should use this edited code in your AllAppsActivity.java.

Comment: But this does not solve my error, in fact it gives me more errors, I just need being able to manage the switch on snippet_list_row.xml from  AllAppsActivity.java

Comment: Switch appSwitch = (Switch) rowView.findViewById(R.id.app_switch);

Comment: rowView appears in red as if it doesn´t exist, what should I put there?? I have tried with snippet_list_row but it does not work

Comment: in your activity - layout file, you should have included a listview. Editing my answer now.

Comment: @Javierd98 : check this edited answer. The elements defined in the custom array adapter, are references to elements in your *app_list_item_layout* xml file, whereas the appListView defined in your onCreate() is a reference to your main activity xml file, which should contain a listview element.

Comment: @SoulRayder, was thinking about the onClickListener here. Don't you think onClickListerner inside getView() is wrong as it will be called every time the listview updates rows when scrolling?

Comment: @Keshav : onclick() method won't be called unless user actually clicks on a list item. I have tried and used this code in two of my apps :)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @SoulRayder, what sould I put on IconType? It may be a silly question, but I don´t know...

Comment: Edited: Also, on    
setListAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(this, arrayOfApps ,arrayOfAppIcons)); does not seem to work, arrayOfApps and arrayOfAppIcons are in red and says cannot resolve symbol "its name"
What should I do?

Comment: @Javierd98 First of all, its setAdapter, not setListAdapter, second of all, you need to separate your input data into those two arrays, one for app names, one for app icons and then feed it into the method.

Comment: @Javierd98 My first guess would be an ImageView for the icontype, but it could be something else too, based on your requirement. Search google based on other code examples for that.

Comment: @Javierd98 : There was a small typo in the code, both the appnames and appicons are arrays, one a string array, and one an array of icontypes. Made the edit.

Comment: Okay, so i´m now using this to get the app names and icons: http://codebucket.co.in/android-get-list-of-all-installed-apps/ 
But it gets the icons as Drawables, and it can´t be chaged to Image, as it says that the function return a Drawable.
I´ve changed all the iconType to Drawable and it does not gives errors, but the problem is that the CustomArrayAdapter gives me an error on the line: 
super(context, R.layout.notificacions_apps_list_row, appnames);
As appnames is not String[] but just String, which is what the function on the link returns. How can I fix that??

Comment: You would have to collect all the app names from the list and put it into the string array appnames, and you can also modify my code for the types used in that link if you want. As for the drawable, you can set that directly as the image by changing the icontype.

Comment: I have now this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778535/installed-apps-listview-doesn%C2%B4t-work
But I don´t know why it does not work

Comment: I will look into the other question. Since I solved this part of your question, plz consider accepting and upvoting my answer in this post.